# MPMusicPlayerController.nowPlayingItem not recording when 2nd song starts

Tags: ios, swift

I have successfully gotten the information about the current song playing, but when the song changes the information for the second song does not get recorded. How do I get the program to record more than one song?

```
let nowPlaying = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer().nowPlayingItem
let playing = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo
let Title = nowPlaying.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as! String
let Artist = nowPlaying.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtist) as! String
let Album = nowPlaying.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) as! String
let duration = nowPlaying.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration) as! NSNumber
let change = nowPlaying.valueForProperty(MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification) as! String

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var ID3 = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var ID3 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,400,400))
    ID3.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
    ID3.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    ID3.text = (("Song: " + Title) + "\n" + ("Artist: " + Artist) + "\n" + ("Album: " + Album))
    ID3.numberOfLines = 3
    self.view.addSubview(ID3)


    //prints into the console what song is currently playing
    println("Song: " + Title)
    println("Artist: " + Artist)
    println("Album: " + Album)
    println(change)
```

Comment: I don't understand. Are you trying to get the info of the next song (whereas it's has played yet?), or are you waiting for when the song change to show the info? If the, `MPMusicPlayerController` can give you the info when it's current music change (look at the doc).

Comment: When the song changes I want the program to log the songs info in the console, I've checked the document I couldn't find anything. For example, song x is playing and the information is logged, but once song y starts playing, song y's info is not logged.

Comment: Look at `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification`.

Comment: I'm getting a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error

Comment: That's a classical Swift error (I don't speak Swift, so I can't help you, but that's an issue that we can found a lot in StackOverFlow or the web in general, plus without your try/code causing this error, we can't guess what's wrong).

Comment: I updated the code with the `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification`

Comment: That's not how to use it! You have to use `NSNotificationCenter` and `beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications` if I remember well.

Comment: hmmm ok I'll check that out.

Comment: I added `nowPlaying.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications`, but I get the error `MPMediaItem does not have a member named beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications`, I use MPMediaItem for the song title, etc.